# How to access info from an instance from another instance in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, object, instance

I am just started learning OOP concepts and to help myself learning, I have created a Characters class. From this class I have made instance called main and an instance called monster. Here is the code for the class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Character {

public:
string name;
float health;
int attackLevel;
int defenseLevel;

void setAttr(string sName,float sHealth, int sAttackLevel, int sDefenseLevel)  {
    name = sName;
    health = sHealth;
    attackLevel = sAttackLevel;
    defenseLevel = sDefenseLevel;

}



void attack(int whatInstanceToAttack)  {

    whatInstanceToAttack.hitpoints -= 20;  //obviously not valid but how do i do this?

    return whatInstanceToAttack;
}
int defend(string defend)  {

    int damageRelieved = defenseLevel * 2;
    return damageRelieved;
}




};
int main() {
Character main;
Character monster;
main.setAttr("Rafael",200,100,30);
monster.setAttr("Monster1",30,40,30);
cout << "Default Values for Raf are;" << endl;
cout << main.name << endl;
cout << main.health<< endl;
cout << main.attackLevel << endl;
cout << main.defenseLevel << endl;


cout << "Default values for monster are" << endl;
cout <<monster.name << endl;
cout <<monster.health << endl;
cout << monster.attackLevel<< endl;
cout << monster.defenseLevel << endl;



return 0;
}
```

Basically what I want to do is somehow access the monster instance via the main instance. I want to do this by running the attack method. So if I run

```
main.attack(monster);
```

then I want the monster to lose 20 hitpoints.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If you don't pass an `int` but a `Character&` (reference to a Character) to `attack`, it should work better.

Comment: Just noticing that you attempt to have your `attack` function return an `int` value, which won't work because `attack` has been declared as a `void` function (ie, it doesn't return a value). There's some reading on function arguments and return types [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to pass reference of Character in attack method.
I think you must be aware of pass by value and pass by reference concept. If not you can read it [here](http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/passby.html)

```
void attack(Character &whatInstanceToAttack)  {

    whatInstanceToAttack.hitpoints -= 20;  //obviously not valid but how do i do this?

}
```

Comment: Thanks I got it to work! I have infact read over pointers and references today as well so I probably should have thought about it myself. Neverless thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access the variables of an instance from another instance of the same class. You need to use a reference to the object to ensure the changes are reflected in the other instance. So here is what your attack function should look like.

```
void attack(Character &c)
{
    c.hitpoints - = 20;
}
```

Now when you call main.attack(monster) from the `main()` function, the `hitpoints` of monster will get decremented by 20.

As a side note, it is considered a good practice to make the data members of a class private, to avoid illegal access/modification of the data. Always use the member functions as an interface to your class instances.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Also for the side note, how would I access the variables. E.g. would I have to make a function to return the private variable instead?

Comment: Yes you could use public member functions to get and set values of the private data members. This way you can always validate the usage of data members. eg. Let's say your name should not be null, then this can be validated in the set function.

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind for future cases. Is my way of setting the attributes (the function setAttr) the best way to do so as I sort of just made it up

Comment: Well, it acceptable, but a better practice will be to use a [class constructor](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm).

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help this is really greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

overload the method attack and you can pass by value or reference as per your requirement.

void attack(Character chr)
or
void attack(Character &chr)

Comment: `void attack(Character chr) ` won't work. The point is to change the value in the instance. So call by value won't have any significance.